# what happens if I delete the file onto which a c++ program is writing data to?

Tags: c++, exception, fstream, file-handling

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    fstream f;
    f.open("test.txt" , ios::app);
    string s="Hello";
    if(f.is_open()){
        cout << "File Open"<<endl;
        f << s;
        sleep(15);
        if(f.is_open()){
            cout << "Still Open" << endl;
        }else{
            cout << "Not Open" << endl;
        }
        s= "Hey \n";
        f<< s;
    }else{
        cout << "Not open" << endl;
    }
    f.close();
    }
}
```

This code will write contents to `test.txt` file upon normal execution.
But if I delete the file while the program is running, then I find that the program throws no exception and it exits successfully. But I do not find the file `text.txt` after I deleted it.

What should I do to know whether writing to the file is happening successfully?

Comment: What is `s` btw?

Comment: What about if you successfully wrote the file and then someone deleted it ***afterwards***? I think you can generally assume that no one is sabotaging your files while you are working on them. It is the Operating System's job to keep intruders out and to ensure than other users can not damage your data. So, unless you have a habit of deleting your own files while you are working on them, you should be okay.

Comment: Answer depends on which operating system you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on operating system you are using.

On Windows, the OS will prevent you from removing such file in first place.

On Linux, the OS will let you remove such file, but will keep handle to this file until it'll be freed by process which use it (in this case, when `fstream` will release resource).

Comment: But How would I know that writing to the file is not going to lead any result? Thanks

Comment: @Shray There is a tool on Linux called [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) which can do the trick; however, the true question is: Is this really an issue? Is there's a real possibility that someone will remove such file? If not, then it's not worth the effort :)

Comment: Thank you sir, really appreciate your time :)

Comment: sir can I get your email id? @Rhathin

Comment: @Shray Sorry, but it's private. If you've more issues you need help with, then just ask a new question :)

Comment: Haha okay sir, I just saw your profile and it had data analyst so wanted to have just a little talk with you. :D

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux the file continues to exist until the program closes the *fstream*, but that doesn't mean you see it through *ls*. When the *fstream* is closed the file is really removed